Issues with Variable Matching in UI Selector in Power Automate Desktop
I have a question regarding the use of variables in UI selectors in Power Automate Desktop. I’m trying to build a selector that match any Name that contains the value of %CurrentItem4%
However, I’ve noticed that Power Automate Desktop does not treat %CurrentItem% as a variable, and it fails to match the element whose Name should contain this value. Any ideas how to solve this?
My current selector looks like this:
treeitem[Name@=".*%CurrentItem%.*"]
